# Can I print result that has only ($) variable in it

Tags: python

```
import os
def find_method(name):
          found = False
    for i, line in enumerate(file(name, "r")):
        for key in found_dic:
            if key in line.strip():
                found_dic[key].append("LINE:"+str(i)+":" + line.strip())
                found = True
```

QUESTION:
As u see in the import os it prints all the result. (ex. include) if include is in the file it print all of file, but I just want to print ex) include $ <-- like this how to fix this print only if there is $variable in the file with search words.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please give an example of what you get and what you expect to get for a given input. Also, use complete words and separate the question into sentences to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if '$' in s` to check if string `s` contains character `$`.

If I get your question, you perhaps want to change

```
            for r in found_dic[key]:
               print "  ",r
```

to

```
            for r in found_dic[key]:
                if key != "include" or '$' in r:
                    print "  ",r
```